# Is there a mathematical equation for making a line from a set of unordered points?

Tags: linear-algebra, spherical-coordinates

I'm currently working with WGS84 coordinates, like so:

[Points example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycG4H.png)

Those points are unordered and have no co-relation between them besides being distributed on a line that can have different angles(Streets have different shapes).

I'm trying to make a line from those set of points, like so:
[Line from points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCpnQ.png)

The line itself has no special conditions apart from retaining the same shape that can be observed from such points and having the same length.
As a human, drawing given line is an easy task, but translating those instructions to a computer algorithm, so far, has been proven kinda difficult.

The first solution i came with is using a [Voronoi Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) to find the farthest-points, that are the ones where the area is the largest given the bounding box(World map). After finding given points, i use [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), iterating over each point to start drawing a line.
It works, but recently i found out about [Linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares), that do exactly what i need, however, the result is a line equation that goes to infinity.

I tried also ordering the values by latitude and longitude, and so goes on, but i ended up in the same problems of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456683/plot-line-from-gps-points).

Is there any equation that does that? **Create a line from given set of points respecting its limits and shape?**

Comment: I think what you want is linear regression. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: @EthanBolker Linear regression results in a line equation, i'm looking for fixed values, like [1,1 to 10,10].

Comment: Then couldn't you just do linear regression and take the x-coordinate values of the two outermost ("outermost" meaning largest and smallest values, whatever they may be) points and plug them in?

Comment: If your only complaint about the least squares approximation is that the resulting line extends infinitely, just come up with a criterion for deciding where to cut off the line. A simple but reliable one might be to find, for each data point, the closest point on the line. Given this list of points on the line that minimize distance to each data point, cut the line off at those with the largest and smallest parameter values ("parameter" here refers to the parameter of the line, like (but not necessarily) $x$ in $y=mx+b$).

Comment: @TheoC. That algorithm isn't foolproof-- imagine a set of points scattered about a vertical line. That with the largest $x$ coordinate need not have the largest $y$ coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Basic linear regression:

[image]

Terminate the line wherever you wish.

Comment: It seems clear that the OP knows about linear regression. His issue seems to be in the "terminate the line" part.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to terminate the line in a way that it works for both vertical scatter and horizontal scatter or even both at same time?

Comment: @NickLeBlanc I would suggest the approach outlined in my comment to the question, using the formulas here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation

Comment: @jawheele I'll give it a shot and report soon as i can, appreciate :)